# Android activity is running twice

Tags: android

I was running my application on a nexus 7 2013 and in logcat I noticed some logs running twice. After writing few more logs I concluded that every activity was running twice on tablet. The strange think is that on phone ( LG G3 or Samsung galaxy s4 mini ) logs are printed only 1 time.

After doing some research I have tried to add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` or `singleTask` or `singleInstance` but none worked. Also I have some intents in activities with the flag:                 `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` and 2 `AsyncTasks`.

Is there a way that the intents or the asynctask cause the problem ?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.marian.digimusicstream" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!--
     To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
     option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" /> <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">

            <!-- <intent-filter> -->
            <!-- <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> -->
            <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> -->
            <!-- </intent-filter> -->
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".musicPlayer"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_music_player">

            <!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar" -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".PlayerService" />
        <service android:name=".audioService" />

        <receiver android:name=".PlayPauseReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".musicPlayer$MusicNoisyReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".singleMusicScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_single_music_screen" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity:

```
public class musicPlayer extends DrawerActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_player);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        pullToRefresh = (PullRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.pullToReresh);
        musicListLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());

        progressBar = new ProgressBar(getApplicationContext());

        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = pref.edit();

        getUser = pref.getString("sharedUser", "");
        getPassword = pref.getString("sharedPass", "");

        new doLogin().execute();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_music_player, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Do Here what ever you want do on back press;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public boolean isFirstItemCompletelyVisible() {
        return mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        musicList.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pullToRefresh.setEnabled(isFirstItemCompletelyVisible());
            }
        });
    }

    private class doLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            Intent myIntent = getIntent();
            boolean button = myIntent.getBooleanExtra("LoginButton", false);

            if (!pref.getBoolean("isCheckBoxChecked", false) && !button) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(musicPlayer.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                cancel(true);
            }

            if (button) {
                getUser = myIntent.getStringExtra("userLogin");
                getPassword = myIntent.getStringExtra("passLogin");
            }

            Log.i("TEST", "User: " + getUser + " pass: " + getPassword);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Log.i("TEST", "Init");

                api = DefaultClientFactory.create(host, getUser, getPassword);
                Log.i("TEST", "" + api.getUserInfo());

                return true;
            } catch (StorageApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (!result) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(musicPlayer.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid E-mail or Password !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
//                new backgroundTask().execute();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure its running twice or there just refrenece to the Activity twice?

Comment: Yes, everything is running twice, my both asynctasks are running twice, onCreate is running twice.

Comment: please post manifest and Activity

Comment: mate you start the loginActivity onPreExecute then onPostExecute why?

Comment: in OnPresExecute I check if I can do the auto login ( if there are username and password setted in sharedPref for example and in PostExecute I switch back to login screen because username or password is incorrect.

Comment: I have added two logs before that intents and none of them are called, so the problem is not there,

Comment: ok so having         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); while I have orientation locked on landscape on nexus 7 make my activity to run twice, why ? after switching orientation to auto everything was running once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

activity launch modes should be used carefully.

android:launchMode="singleTop"

**If instance of activity is present on top of Task stack, a new instance will not be created and system will route your intent information through onNewIntent(). If it is not present on top, a new instance will be created. Multiple instance can be created and each instance may belong to different task.** ([Good post on activity launch mode](http://androidsrc.net/android-activity-launch-mode-example/))

1. Why you are checking shared pref in onPreExecute() and then canceling it.? A better way would be to execute asynctask after checking this.
2. **cancel(true)** does not guarantee that it will stop async task as soon as called. A better way would be to add **isCancelled() check** in doInBackground(), if cancelled return result as required. It will help to finish asynctask at earliest without performing task written over there.
3. In manifest, you might want to add android:conifgChanges for better handing of orientation.

   **android:configChanges**=["mcc", "mnc", "locale",
                                    "touchscreen", "keyboard", "keyboardHidden",
                                    "navigation", "screenLayout", "fontScale",
                                    "uiMode", "orientation", "screenSize",
                                    "smallestScreenSize"]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This might seem silly, but double-check that you are not logging things twice. I thought two instances of my MainActivity were running at the same time, no matter what I tried. Then I realized I had planted two of Jake Wharton's Timber debug trees and it was logging everything twice.